# Data grid view show one to one relationship

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one to one relationship between two tables like this:

Person: id,First name,Last name,Date of birth

person info:person id,address,email,mobile

I want to show the user first name , last name and email in data grid view , 
when i am trying to bind person object with data grid view data source like this

```
grdPerson.DataSource = objPerson;
```

I get all the person object columns , but i get one empty column for person info object , so how i can show the email and mobile field?

Comment: Do you use Linq? Is that relation in database (primary and foreign keys)? Can you use POCO class, or extend your current class Person? Or maybe, the best solution, it would be to create view on databese, that have all fields you need, and use that View to fill DataDrid (I'm using that in my solutions).

Comment: I am using ADO.net entity model , and i work on automatic generated code.

Comment: I would try to do something, like "e.personinfo.mobile". If it fails,  you can use temporaty "POCO" class, that will map each field separate (create one class, that have all fields from Person and Person Info as primitive types). Alter, you can use View. Join that relation in db, and use in your app view (master obcject and dictionaries as one obj). I'm using that approach in Reporting Services (Data grid for web is much intelligent).

Comment: I don't want to use POCO , i think put those two tables in one table is the best solution , or create a view to join those two tables , what do you think?

Comment: In your situation both solution are good. If join those tables don't break normalization rules, you can join them into one table. If join them can break normalization rules, use view.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation both solution are good. If join those tables don't break normalization rules, you can join them into one table. If join them can break normalization rules, use view.

If it helpfull, you can mark this answare as solution.